# window.orientation is not working in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, orientation

I am using 3.2 and 4.0 iOs and I am trying to run html file in UIWebView.
the html file contains to following lines:

```
var pwint = function(text) {
 var output = document.getElementById('output');
 output.innerHTML = output.innerHTML + text + '\n';
};

var reorient = function(e) {
 pwint('Window Orientation: ' + window.orientation); 
};

window.onorientationchange = reorient
```

The problem is that `window.orientation` always returns '0' while I run the same code in safari it works as expected.

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try applying it to `document.body.onorientationchange`.